# Why am I getting a post request instead of a get request?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am using flask as my backend. Every time I request a post method from "/api-quotes", it also requests a post method from "/home" even though it only has a get method. I keep getting the error message, "The method is not allowed for the requested URL." on the browser. Is there any way to fix this problem?

`<Button onClick={() => {axios.post('/api-quotes', {text: predictMessage})}} type="submit">Generate</Button>`

This is my React form.

````
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Flask, jsonify, request, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_session import Session
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, desc
import os
import logging 
import random

basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

app = Flask("__name__")
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'posts2.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'quotes': 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'quotes.db')}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    displayName = db.Column(db.String)
    image = db.Column(db.String)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
    username = db.Column(db.String)#, nullable=False)
    verified = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    avatar = db.Column(db.String)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, id, displayName, image, text, username, verified, avatar):
        self.id = id
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.image = image
        self.text = text
        self.username = username
        self.verified = verified
        self.avatar = avatar

class PostsSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'displayName', 'image', 'text', 'username', 'verified', 'avatar', 'date_created')

post_schema = PostsSchema()
posts_schema = PostsSchema(many=True)

@app.route("/api", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = Posts.query.order_by('id').all()[-1].id + 1
        displayName = request.json['displayName'] 
        print(request.get_json())
        image = request.json['image'] 
        text = request.json['text'] 
        username = request.json['username'] 
        verified = request.json['verified']
        avatar = request.json['avatar']
        new_posts = Posts(id, displayName, image, text, username, verified, avatar)
        db.session.add(new_posts)
        db.session.commit()
        print(db)
        return post_schema.jsonify(new_posts)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        all_posts = Posts.query.order_by(desc(Posts.id))
        result = posts_schema.dump(all_posts)
        return jsonify(result)

class Quotes(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'quotes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, id, category, text):
        self.id = id
        self.category = category
        self.text = text

class QuotesSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'text')

quote_schema = QuotesSchema()
quotes_schema = QuotesSchema(many=True)

@app.route("/api-quotes", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def apiquotes():
    items = ['Good days will come.', 'Keep calm and carry on!',
    'Treat others the way you want to be treated', 'Life is meaningless without happiness',
    'They may have talent, but you have determination']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Post request to quotes")
        id = Quotes.query.order_by('id').all()[-1].id + 1
        category = 'quotes' 
        text = items[random.randrange(len(items))]
        new_quotes = Quotes(id, category, text)
        print("Inserting to new_quotes")
        db.session.add(new_quotes)
        print("Added new quotes")
        db.session.commit()
        print("Returning quotes")
        print(new_quotes)
        print(quote_schema.jsonify(new_quotes))
        return quote_schema.jsonify(new_quotes)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("Sending get to quotes")
        all_quotes = Quotes.query.order_by(desc(Quotes.id))
        result = quotes_schema.dump(all_quotes)
        return jsonify(result)

@app.route("/home", methods = ['GET'])
def my_index():
    print("Getting /home")
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

Comment: How do you make the request? Is it an HTML form? Post the source code for that too please.

Comment: You can look into the devtools(F12)-> netowrk tab in your browser to know the initiator of your POST for home...

Comment: @Selcuk I'm using React. I updated it with the form code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with your HTML/javascript/react code.  You didn't have all the html in your question, but I think it will look something like this:

```html
<form method=POST>
<button onclick="console.log('posting your api')" type=submit>Press Me</button>
</form>
```

You likely have a button in a form.  When you click the button the onclick js is posting as you expect.

There is likely a form that your button is connected to given that you set the type to submit.  The form is likely configured to post to the current page which I am guessing is `/home`.